# Delete specific files in directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm uploading PDF files into a folder using `FileUpload` control in this way:

```
string pdfFilPath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
string pdfPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/" + pdfFilPath);
FileUploadFoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(pdfPath);
```

But at the same time I'm inserting an `Id`, `Description` and `PDFUrl` in the database for this file:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Book(Description, PDFUrl) 
  VALUES (''' + textBoxDescription.Text + "','" + "~/PDF/" + pdfFilPath + "')", conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

If I select all columns from the database and show them on a `GridView`, they appear as follows:

```
ID       Description              PDFUrl
1       In this book...     ~/PDF/jQuery in Action.pdf
```

Now, if I want to delete a book review, all I do is `("DELETE FROM Book Where Id='" + textBoxId.Text + "'", conn);`, but this will delete only the `Id`,`Description` and the `PDFUrl` from the database.

My question is: How can I delete the PDF file at the same time when I delete the review from the database?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get the PDFUrl from the database and do a simple file delete?  You would use the GridView RowDeleting Event.

Comment: Like: `File.Delete(Server.MapPath(@"~/PDF/" + pdfFilPath));` - code taken from OP's posted question for uploading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget though, you should check to see if the file exists before you delete it or else it will throw an error. This can happen if the user refreshes the postback.

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(PDFUrl))
{
    File.Delete(Server.MapPath(PdfUrl));
}
```

Comment: You are correct. FWIW in my answer I used `FileInfo` because it doesn't have this problem. Neither of our answers, however, address other Exceptions that may occur, like if he doesn't have permissions or the file is set to Read Only.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is the ID, then first fun a query to get the PDFUrl from the DB based on the ID.

Then:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(PDFUrl));
fi.Delete;
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also, you should *really* use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) for reasons explained on the [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a method which delete the file from the directory, after that you delete the file from the database.

```
public void DeleteFile(string id)
{
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(PDFUrl));
fi.Delete;

SqlComand cmd = new SqlComand("DELETE FROM Book Where Id='" + textBoxId.Text + "'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```